# Is there a better way to determine the function in the integrand?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, problem-solving

I need to find $U(z)$ given that $\Delta\ll 1$. 
$$\int_{-\Delta/2}^{\Delta/2} U(z) \, dz = C$$ $C$ and $\Delta$ are constants.

Since $\Delta$ is small I am just using 
$$ U(z) = C / \Delta\,.$$ It works pretty well but was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Should not it be $\frac{C}{\Delta}$?

Comment: yes, it was typo...

Comment: Take a look at mollifiers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Comment: Is your $U$ allowed to depend on $\Delta$? Or just $z$? If only on $z$ no such _function_ $U$ will exist.

Comment: @mickep yes it depends on $\Delta$, the smaller $\Delta$ is the larger is the absolute value of $U(z)$ is and vice versa. In the limit $\Delta \to 0$ then $U(z) \to -\infty$

Comment: Your solution is OK, but you can also add any odd function to your $U$.

Comment: @mickep Thanks. Could you expand on why I would want to add an odd function? I am not sure I follow the reasoning.

Comment: I don't say that you want to do that, just that you can, i.e. your solution is not the only one. But stick with it, it is very natural.